# Is there any DAX Measure that Count rows that have an ID matching another row, but a different value in the column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with ID and with different statuses but some are not having both. I need create measure that will give the count for all the ID's that are having different statues.

I have tried below Dax functions but not giving the expected results.

```
Link-EC-Count =
VAR count_Donor =
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( MagentaBuilt_Linked[Microwave IQ Link ID] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLEXCEPT ( MagentaBuilt_Linked, MagentaBuilt_Linked[Microwave IQ Link ID] ),
            MagentaBuilt_Linked[Site_Nature] = "Donor"
        ),
        FILTER (
            MagentaBuilt_Linked,
            MagentaBuilt_Linked[Primary AAV Vendor] = "T-Mobile"
        )
    )
VAR count_Recepient =
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( MagentaBuilt_Linked[Microwave IQ Link ID] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLEXCEPT ( MagentaBuilt_Linked, MagentaBuilt_Linked[Microwave IQ Link ID] ),
            MagentaBuilt_Linked[Site_Nature] = "Recipient"
        ),
        FILTER (
            MagentaBuilt_Linked,
            MagentaBuilt_Linked[Primary AAV Vendor] = "T-Mobile"
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( count_Donor > 0 && count_Recepient > 0, 1, 0 )
```

Here is the sample data looks like
[image]

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a calculated column formula for "Eligible Row?" that works:

```
Eligible Row? = 
IF(
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS('Table'),
        FILTER('Table',
            'Table'[Affiliate ID]=EARLIER('Table'[Affiliate ID]) && 
            'Table'[Achievement Type] <> EARLIER('Table'[Achievement Type])))>0,
    "Yes","No")
```

The idea is to filter the table for rows when the Affiliate ID matches, then filter for rows where the Achievement is different, then count the rows.

[image]

Here are formulas for my two intermediate calculated columns:

```
Count ID = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Table'),
    FILTER('Table',
        'Table'[Affiliate ID]=EARLIER('Table'[Affiliate ID])))

Count Other Achievements = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Table'),
    FILTER('Table',
        'Table'[Affiliate ID]=EARLIER('Table'[Affiliate ID]) && 
        'Table'[Achievement Type] <> EARLIER('Table'[Achievement Type])))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think This is what you need. Try this code as measure:

```
Count ID = 
VAR TblSummary = ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE('Sheet 1','Sheet 1'[Affiliate Id],'Sheet 1'[Achievement Type]),
    "UniqueCount",CALCULATE(COUNT('Sheet 1'[Affiliate Id]),ALLEXCEPT('Sheet 1','Sheet 1'[Affiliate Id]))
)
RETURN
    SUMX(TblSummary,IF([UniqueCount]>1,[UniqueCount]))
```

If we test it on a visual:

[image: Blue Framework]